# How to show sum of all visible series' data dynamically

Tags: highcharts

How can I display SUM of all visible series' data in highchart at any given time? For example given this chart:

https://jsfiddle.net/8xmw2nj6/2/

It shows a simple stacked column graph with drilldown. What I want is that by default it should show '14879' value. As visible series/drilldown change, it should update this value. This value can be shown in graph title for instance.

Any idea on how to accomplish this?

Example of why it is important:
Column graph that shows 12 months breakdown (in a given year) of total sales. We can see the sales per month, but it is important to know the total too. Highlight only series of a particular customer - again, we want to know the total value of the series too, not only the breakdown per month.

I know we can set a title of a chart with `setTitle`:

```
chart.setTitle(total);
```

But I have no idea where to include this functionality and how to calculate the total of only visible series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve what you are after by using the `setTitle` function and the `render` event like this:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    render: function() {
      let series = this.series
      let sum = 0
      for(let i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
        if(series[i].visible){
          for(let j = 0; j < series[i].data.length; j++) {
            sum += series[i].data[j].y
          }
        }
      }
    this.setTitle({text: "Production Orders, sum: " + sum}, false, false) 
    }
  }
},
```

This will calculate the sum of all *visible* series, at all times.

To format the number in the title you can use `Highcharts.numberFormat(number, decimals [, decimalPoint] [, thousandsSep])` which returns a formated number as a string instead of the integer `sum`.

**Working example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/y03qjbhk/1/

**API on render event:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

Comment: Just one question - how would you call a default number format function of HighCharts on the sum? That is, we can specify things like thousandsep and decimalPoint in settings, so I'd like to call the function to format the sum with these parameters in place.

Comment: I have updated the answer to show how you can properly format the number now.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've actually oped out to put the sum in subtitle, as it makes the most sense and looks nice by default. Replacing last line (`this.setTitle...`) by `this.subtitle.update({text: Highcharts.numberFormat(sum, 0)})` - this will by default use the Highcharts' set decimalPoint and thousandsSep